# How to keep two tables stick together within one page?

Tags: tables, positioning, text

I have two table in my latex project, whereas I first describe the main context of the first table, then render the table after that text. In my context, my first table is a bit of large (fit half of pages), then I give new line sentences to continue my discussion and render the second table (it is the small table). However, in latex output, the position of table and text is not aligned perfectly. How can I control the position of table whereas given text comes first then table comes after?

Here is my latex code:

```
%% 5~6 line text

\begin{table}
\centering
  \caption{MuSERA parameter setup}
  \label{tab:parameter setup}
  \noindent\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}\begin{tabularx}{1.25\linewidth}{|c|c| >{\arraybackslash}X|} \hline
\diagbox[width = 5cm, height =1.25cm]{Param. list}{\raisebox{5ex}{Name}}
& Parameter & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Description} \\\hline
\hline
\multirowcell{2}{Replicate Type} & Biological & biological replicates exhibit biologically similar results\\\hline
\multirow{3}*{Thresholds} & $T^{w} = 1.0e-04 $ & stringent enrichment threshold\\
\cline{2-3}
& $T^{s} = 1.0e-08 $ & weakly enrichment threshold\\
\cline{2-3}
& $\gamma = 1.0e-08 $ & combined stringency threshold\\
\hline
\multirowcell{2}{Multiple Testing \\correction} & FDR = 0.05 & false discovery rate to correct the p-value\\\hline
\multirowcell{2}{Multiple Overlap\\ ERs treatment} & Use most stringent peak & choose the most stringent \ac{er} (with lowest p-value) from multiple overlapping\\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

%% 5~6 line text

\settowidth\mylen{wgEncodeOpenChromChip}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
  \caption{\textit{MuSERA output}}
  \label{tab:MuSERA output}
\begin{tabular}{@{}m{\mylen}ccccccc@{}}
    \toprule
    Replicate & total ERs & $R^{s}$ & $R^{w}$ & $R^{c}$ & $R^{d}$ & $R^{mtc}$ & outputset\\
    \midrule
    wgEncodeOpenChromChip K562CmycAlnRep1 & 283 & 158 & 125 & 241 & 42 & 241 & 241 \\
    wgEncodeOpenChromChip K562CmycAlnRep2 & 459 & 230 & 229 & 465 & 195 & 266 & 266 \\
    wgEncodeOpenChromChip K562CmycAlnRep3 & 297 & 109 & 188 & 368 & 107 & 191 & 191 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Which document class do you use? Which packages do you load? How or where are the `\diagbox`, `\multirowcell`, and `\ac` macros defined?

Comment: @Mico I used `\documentclass{ituthesis}`, and I used `\usepackage{array, tabularx, multirow, booktabs, diagbox}
` and `\usepackage{makecell}`, which are defined in my preamble.

Comment: Is the `ituthesis` document class available online somewhere?

Comment: @Mico or how to fit above two table stick together in one page? I could use cross reference with corresponding text? Any idea? let me know if you intend to check my project, so I could share it with you.

Comment: If you're OK with making both `tabular` environments and their associated `\caption` directives be part of a single `table` environment, that would probably be the easiest solution.

Comment: @Mico I don't understand your comment. Could you please elaborate it with an answer? Is that possible to have a look my latex project if I invite you? Thank you very much.

Comment: You could alternatively prevent them from being floats altogether. Leave away the `table` environment and only typeset them as `tabular` exactly where you want them (without `LaTeX` moving them around). `captionof` of the `caption` package then allows you to typeset captions for them as if they were regular tables.

Comment: @Dan - I've posted an answer based on my (almost certainly inadequate) understanding of your objectives. If I've misunderstood what you're trying to achieve, just leave a comment below the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your main issues correctly (and I may not have...), you're concerned that the `tabularx` and `tabular` environments are wider than the parameter `\textwidth`.

If that's the case, I suggest you use a `tabularx` environment (with width set to `\textwidth`) and a `tabular*` environment instead. To keep them from floating too far from the text portions that directly precede them, consider assigning `[ht!]` location specifiers for both `table` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % I don't have the file "ituthesis.cls"
\usepackage{array, tabularx, multirow, booktabs, 
            diagbox, makecell, amsmath, calc, ragged2e}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\providecommand\ac[1]{#1} % ??
\newlength\mylen
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}

\caption{MuSERA parameter setup}
\label{tab:parameter setup}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|p{3.25cm-2\tabcolsep}|c| >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X|} 
\hline
\diagbox[width = 3.25cm, height =1.25cm]{Param. list}{Name}
& Parameter & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Description} \\
\hline\hline
\multirowcell{2}{Replicate Type} & Biological & biological replicates exhibit biologically similar results\\
\hline
\multirow{6}{*}{Thresholds} 
  & $T^{w} = 1.0e{-}04 $ & stringent enrichment threshold\\
  \cline{2-3}
  & $T^{s} = 1.0e{-}08 $ & weakly enrichment threshold\\
  \cline{2-3}
  & $\gamma = 1.0e{-}08 $ & combined stringency threshold\\
\hline
\multirowcell{2}{Multiple Testing \\correction} & FDR${} = 0.05$ & false discovery rate to correct the $p$\nobreakdash-value\\
\hline
\multirowcell{2}{Multiple Overlap\\ ERs treatment} & Use most stringent peak & choose the most stringent \ac{er} (with lowest $p$\nobreakdash-value) from multiple overlapping\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2] % filler text

\begin{table}[h!]
\settowidth\mylen{wgEncodeOpenChromChip}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\caption{\textit{MuSERA output}}
  \label{tab:MuSERA output}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}m{\mylen}*{7}{c}}
    \toprule
    Replicate & total ERs & $R^{s}$ & $R^{w}$ & $R^{c}$ & $R^{d}$ & $R^{mtc}$ & outputset\\
    \midrule
    wgEncodeOpenChromChip K562CmycAlnRep1 & 283 & 158 & 125 & 241 & 42 & 241 & 241 \\
    wgEncodeOpenChromChip K562CmycAlnRep2 & 459 & 230 & 229 & 465 & 195 & 266 & 266 \\
    wgEncodeOpenChromChip K562CmycAlnRep3 & 297 & 109 & 188 & 368 & 107 & 191 & 191 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

%% still more text

\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I avoid that spanish text?

Comment: Do you mean the fake-Latin filler paragraph? Just omit the instruction `\lipsum[2]`.

Comment: I think your approach is great. I got rid of param list table that massed up my project, while keep using your improvement. Plus any way I could simplify param list table (don't add description column, just get plain table is enough for me). Any idea?

Comment: @Dan - I'm afraid I don't understand the background, objective, and contents of the first table sufficiently to give advice on matters of contents. Sorry.

Comment: Dear Mico, regarding the output of your solution, how can I highlight one particular cell and use cross-reference for corresponding text?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly then you want the content to occur as text-table-text-table. You probably don't want the tables to float at all. Try this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array, tabularx, multirow, booktabs, 
            diagbox, makecell, amsmath, calc, ragged2e}
\newcommand{\ac}[1]{\emph{#1}}
\newlength{\mylen}
\setlength{\mylen}{\textwidth}

\begin{document}

Here are just a few lines of text. This is just to show how the text would run and how the tables would in each case occur directlyafter the text were they are referred to.

\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{MuSERA parameter setup\label{tab:parameter setup}}
\noindent\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|c| >{\arraybackslash}X|} \hline
\diagbox[width = 5cm, height =1.25cm]{Param. list}{\raisebox{5ex}{Name}}
& Parameter & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Description} \\\hline
\hline
\multirowcell{2}{Replicate Type} & Biological & biological replicates exhibit biologically similar results\\\hline
\multirow{3}*{Thresholds} & $T^{w} = 1.0e-04 $ & stringent enrichment threshold\\
\cline{2-3}
& $T^{s} = 1.0e-08 $ & weakly enrichment threshold\\
\cline{2-3}
& $\gamma = 1.0e-08 $ & combined stringency threshold\\
\hline
\multirowcell{2}{Multiple Testing \\correction} & FDR = 0.05 & false discovery rate to correct the p-value\\\hline
\multirowcell{2}{Multiple Overlap\\ ERs treatment} & Use most stringent peak & choose the most stringent \ac{er} (with lowest p-value) from multiple overlapping\\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

Here are just a few lines of text. This is just to show how the text would run and how the tables would in each case occur directlyafter the text were they are referred to.

\settowidth\mylen{wgEncodeOpenChromChip}
\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{\textit{MuSERA output}\label{tab:MuSERA output}}
\begin{tabular}{@{}m{\mylen}ccccccc@{}}
    \toprule
    Replicate & total ERs & $R^{s}$ & $R^{w}$ & $R^{c}$ & $R^{d}$ & $R^{mtc}$ & outputset\\
    \midrule
    wgEncodeOpenChromChip K562CmycAlnRep1 & 283 & 158 & 125 & 241 & 42 & 241 & 241 \\
    wgEncodeOpenChromChip K562CmycAlnRep2 & 459 & 230 & 229 & 465 & 195 & 266 & 266 \\
    wgEncodeOpenChromChip K562CmycAlnRep3 & 297 & 109 & 188 & 368 & 107 & 191 & 191 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

And for god's sake, please provide a proper **working** minimum example next time! There are loads of packages to load and self-defined lengths and commands in your code-snippet which are never loaded or defined in your example because it is no MWE. Had Mico not have figured out which packages to load, I would have never gone through the trouble to do it myself just to answer you.